# APC locking mechanisme alternative for win32

Tags: php, winapi, locking, apc

I want to use APC for php for storing and fetching values (function calls and return values) between a endless running php process and multiple client processes. The endless running process constantly checks for newly stored values.
I am running php as a Apache module on WinXP. For each APC function call a apc.lock.* file is placed in the windows temp directory. My harddisk runs overtime.
Is there an other locking mechanisme that can be used (or disable locking) in for APC?

Answer (score 0):

What about storing the locks in database table? Optionally you can use build-in function [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

Comment: What I want to know is if I can use another locking mechanisme, or disable locking, for APC on win32.